# Merge multiple columns from different tables into one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

tblPeople:

```
ID | Name | DOB
---------------
1  | Alex | 13.12.1988
2  | Phil | 12.07.1976
```

tblEvents:

```
ID | Date       | Description
-----------------------------
1  | 04.07.2019 | Test
```

I want to create a query, which outputs all upcoming events like so:

```
Date       | Description
--------------------------
04.07.2019 | Test
12.07.1976 | Birthday Phil
```

But I can't get it to merge the relevant columns of both tables into one output. I already tried UNION but don't know how to handle additional columns which must not be merged with it.

Comment: You can specify columns in Union so it is not a problem with new ones

Comment: How do you define "upcoming events"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Events like the "Test" on 04.07.2019 or birthdays of people in tblPeople.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join and union

```
select date, Description from tblEvents
union all
select DOB,'Birthday '+Name from tblPeople a inner join tblEvents
on month(date)=month(DOB)
```